# ADM mass in Schoen's paper of positive mass theorem

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, mass, hamiltonian-formalism

I'm reading *[On the Proof of the Positive Mass Conjecture in General Relativity (1979)](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-65/issue-1/On-the-proof-of-the-positive-mass-conjecture-in-general/cmp/1103904790.full)*, and notice that the expression of ADM mass isn't explicitly shown here, instead it's in the description of asyptotically flat initial data set:

Each end of it has metric $$ds^2=(1+M/2r)^4(\sum dx_i^2)+\sum_{i,j}O(1/r^2)dx_idx_j.$$

And through this paper, he is proving that $M$ is non-negative. So I guess $M$ is ADM mass. I know that for Schwarzschild spacetime, $M$ is ADM mass. But does it hold for other cases? If it doesn't, is it to say that this proof holds only for asymptotically Schwarzschild cases?

Later: I know the answer now. The paper in 1979 is indeed about asymptotically Schwarzschild case, but he published another paper in 1981, which is about general cases.

Comment: do you mean "it holds for asymptotically flat cases"?

Comment: If it doesn't hold for other cases, it means it only holds for Schwarzschild/ asymptotically Schwarzschild cases.

Comment: Can you given an example of an asymptotically Schwarzschild metric?

Comment: Well I read this phrase in a book called general relativity by Lee Dan, in which the definition of  asymptotically Schwarzschild manifold includes metrics of that form (Definition 3.7). I don't know about examples.